# the attribute 'type' and a xs:complexType local declaration are mutually exclusive

Tags: python-3.x, django, xml, xsd

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="Field" type="withKey">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Applicants" type="Applicants"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have the following tags in one of my xsd files, while executing the above code, I am getting the error

> xmlschema.validators.exceptions.XMLSchemaParseError: the attribute
> 'type' and a xs:complexType local declaration are mutually exclusive

Running my code on Python 3.9 and django 4.1.  Please help me with the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: This block of code in xsd file is part of my Django code, while running python manage.py makemigrations, this above xsd block is throwing mentioned error

Comment: The error is regarding your XSD, not your Python code.  Remove `type="withKey"` from your `Field` element type declaration because it already has a local type declaration.  Alternatively, remove the local type declaration, assuming that you have a `withKey` type defined.  Use one way or the other to declare the type of `Field` -- not both.

Comment: If I remove type="withkey", I started getting ```xmlschema.validators.exceptions.XMLSchemaParseError: the QName 'Applicants' is mapped to no namespace, but this requires that there is an xs:import statement in the schema without the 'namespace' attribute```

Comment: That's a new problem in your XSD.   After researching the error message and recommended solutions, post a new question if you're still stuck.  ***Include minimal but complete XSD and XML next time as part of a [mcve].***